# Python script to read through a list and grab reverse DNS entry

Tags: python, sockets, networking, reverse-dns, gethostbyaddr

Background: I have always wanted to try my hand at scripting so here goes!

Problem: When gethostbyaddr gets to an IP with no DNS entry it errors and my script doesn't continue on.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import socket

file = 'ServerList'

f = open(file, 'r')

 lines = f.readlines()
 f.close()
 for i in lines:
    host = i.strip()
    if socket.gethostbyaddr(host) return(True):
        val1 = socket.gethostbyaddr(host)
        print("%s - %s" % (host, val1))
    else:
        print ("%s - No Entry" % (host))
```

But it errors probably because the return(True) is not proper syntax.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
J

Comment: `if socket.gethostbyaddr(host):` solve your problem ?

Comment: Did you try the script provided if it worked for you? Consider making it the accepted answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

As for basic syntax, you should remove the `return(True)` as mentioned by [itzmeontv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3160881/itzmeontv).

However, if the method fails it will most likely throw some kind of exception (I tried some servers and got a `socket.gaierror`), so you'll want to catch and handle those cases with `try ... except`:

```
import socket

file = 'ServerList'

f = open(file, 'r')

lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
for i in lines:
    host = i.strip()
    try:
        val1 = socket.gethostbyaddr(host)
        print("%s - %s" % (host, val1))
    except socket.error, exc:
        print ("%s - No Entry, socket error: %s" % (host, exc))
```

I recommend reading through [Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Comment: But not with a bare `except:` - instead use `except socket.gaierror:` or something alike...